# React Native Typescript, Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"200" | "600" etc

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am passing a theme into my style.ts:

```
badgeText: {
  fontWeight: theme.fonts.FONT_WEIGHT_HEAVY,
},
```

Constants:

```
export default {
  FONT_SIZE_EXTRA_SMALL: 8,
  FONT_SIZE_VERY_SMALL: 11,
  FONT_SIZE_SMALL: 14,
  FONT_SIZE_MEDIUM: 16,
  FONT_SIZE_EXTRA_MEDIUM: 18,
  FONT_SIZE_LARGE: 20,
  FONT_SIZE_X_LARGE: 22,
  FONT_SIZE_XX_LARGE: 24,
  FONT_SIZE_XXX_LARGE: 28,
  FONT_WEIGHT_LIGHT: '200',
  FONT_WEIGHT_MEDIUM: '600',
  FONT_WEIGHT_HEAVY: '800',
  LIGHT: 'DINRoundOT-Light',
  MEDIUM: 'DINRoundOT-Medium',
  BOLD: 'DINRoundOT-Bold',
  REGULAR: 'DINRoundOT',
};
```

I get the error below, any ideas?

```
(property) TextStyle.fontWeight?: "200" | "600" | "800" | "normal" | "bold" | "100" | "300" | "400" | "500" | "700" | "900" | undefined
Specifies font weight. The values 'normal' and 'bold' are supported for most fonts. Not all fonts have a variant for each of the numeric values, in that case the closest one is chosen.

Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"200" | "600" | "800" | "normal" | "bold" | "100" | "300" | "400" | "500" | "700" | "900" | undefined'.ts
```

Comment: I would say it's because the `fontWeight` property expects a very specific set of string values that represent the font weight. When you define a constant `FONT_WEIGHT_HEAVY: '800'`, Typescript infers the type as `string`, which is too broad for `fontWeight`. You can fix it by defining your constant as `FONT_WEIGHT_HEAVY: '800' as '800'` which will tell Typescript how it should treat this value, and then it will match the type signature for `fontWeight`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exporting default as JSON format that will cause string type annotation.
It would be better to declare const value for FONT_WEIGHT_HEAVY like this:

```
export const FONT_WEIGHT_HEAVY = '800';
...
```

then you might do in theme file like this:

```
export * from "./Constants";
```